# Google Apps Script: event object('e') keeps being undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I know nothing about coding, but I was required to do some automation job.
Now I'm trying to automate mailing via Google Apps Script.

The problem is, event object('e') is continuously undefined.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRow')

What's the problem here? Any helps would be appreciated.

Here's the full code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('list');
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var rowData = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  var inquirynumber = rowData[headers.indexOf('연번')];
  var board = rowData[headers.indexOf('게시판')];
  var cafenickname = rowData[headers.indexOf('카페닉네임')];
  var naverid = rowData[headers.indexOf('카페아이디')];
  var content = rowData[headers.indexOf('문의내용')];
  var inquirylink = rowData[headers.indexOf("원문보기")];
  var writelink = rowData[headers.indexOf("기록작성")];
  var autolink = rowData[headers.indexOf("자동기록")];

  var timestampColumnIndex = headers.indexOf("접수일시") + 1;
  var timestampCell = sheet.getRange(row, timestampColumnIndex); // rowIndex를 row로 수정

  var timestampValue = timestampCell.getValue(); // 이 값은 문자열 형식으로 가져옵니다.
  var formattedTimestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(timestampValue), "GMT+9", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

  var emailSubject = "[" + board + "] " + inquirynumber + " " + cafenickname + "(" + naverid + ")  |  " + formattedTimestamp;
  var emailBody = "문의자명: " + cafenickname + "(" + naverid + ")" + "\n문의유형: " + board + "\n접수일시: " + formattedTimestamp
                  + "\n\n문의내용: \n" + content + "\n원문보기: " + inquirylink + "\n기록작성: " + writelink + "\n자동기록: " + autolink;

  var recipientEmail = "example@example.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, emailSubject, emailBody);
}
```

I've found out multiple reports saying you should not test event objects via script editor.
So I'm not running this on script editor. I checked the failure on actual run.

Comment: In your script, when `e` is not given, I think that an error like `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')` occurs at the line of `var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('list');`. If your error line is `var row = range.getRow();`, I think that `e.range` is `undefined` while `e` is given. If my understanding is correct, I'm worried that you might have installed `onEdit` function as the OnChange trigger.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the event object of the OnChange trigger doesn't include `range` property. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) By this, such an error occurs. If you want to execute your script by editing cells, please install OnEdit trigger by renaming `onEdit` to another name like `installedOnEdit`. Because, when `onEdit` is installed as the OnEdit trigger, this function is run 2 times. Please be careful about this. Unfortunately, I couldn't know your actual situation. So, I posted my answer as comments. I apologize for this.

Comment: I think the simple answer is that if you run the onEdit(e) function without supplying the event object you get an error if you load and save the onEdit(e) function and then edit the appropriate sheets in  the appropriate manner you will see that the trigger is generated and the function operates correctly.  You might also like to know that simple triggers must complete within 30 seconds or they will terminate

Comment: Please note that your script will be triggered on all edits for all sheets in the spreadsheet

Comment: The problem kept to occur, so I solved this by just removing the e from logic. I appreciate all your comments.